# Are 93% of meat worker marriages in shambles?

Tags: united-states, marriage, meat, cows

In the Youtube video "The Journey of a Beef Cow" (with 1.1M views as of January 2018), Sam O'Nella Academy makes the claim

> The FDA estimates that 93% of meat worker marriages are in shambles

No source is given anywhere in the video or in the description. I would information on both parts of the claim. In other words I would like to know if this is actually an FDA estimation, and if such an estimation is anywhere near accurate. Given the FDA is a part of the US government,the claim is likely restricted to Americans.

Here is the video immediately before the claim: https://youtu.be/MmHiZQRaso0?t=156

Comment: The biggest surprise in this claim is a government agency looking at the personal well-being of workers in an industry.

Comment: The claim (assuming that it is a genuine stat in the first place of course) is meaningless without comparison to marriage status of similarly-paid workers in other industries. It's no great revelation that [people in US lower on sociology-economic ladder are generally in a state of shambled marriage situation](https://www.google.com/search?q=marriage+usa+poor&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1-ab).

Comment: And what is the definition of "in shambled" anyway?

Comment: Too make this a notable claim I expect more than a fictional statement from a cartoon figure.

Comment: Since *[shambles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shambles)* used to mean a area of slaughterhouses and butchers' shops, you wonder whether its use here was deliberate

Comment: @JanDoggen how about a non-fictional statement made by a cartoon figure with a following of more than half a million people? I think this is a credible question if you consider the following of this YouTuber and the views on this specific video.

Comment: @AK_is_curious I don't see how a video with a million views makes it a notable claim...  You could go through this video line for line and find inaccuracies in basically each; because it seems _very_ clear to me that it's not a serious video.   It's a joke/entertainment video.

Comment: It's a pun. Shambles is an old word for slaughterhouse. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shambles

Comment: I'm with @AndrewGrimm on this one.  Why would the FDA, of all agencies, be looking into the marriage status of the industry labor force?  On the flip side, it is a miserable, grueling existence, working in an industrial meat processing facility. If you're doing miserable crappy work for not great pay, chances are other aspects of your life aren't all that wonderful, either, so I wouldn't be surprised if this had some kernel of truth at its core.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I messaged the creator of the video, asking:

> In one of your videos you write "The FDA estimates that 93% of meat worker marriages are in shambles". is that just a joke or do you have a source for this?

Today he replied to me. I quote his reply in full:

[image: lol]

Combine this with the facts that the happiness of a relationship is pretty difficult to quantify, and that the FDA would have no reason or mandate to pry into the personal lives of factory employees, and I think it runs against common sense that a statistic like this actually exists.

Comment: Was this done in public? Is it possible to link to the reply?

Comment: No, it was a private message. I assumed he wouldn't reply to a public YouTube comment

Comment: At least provide a screenshot of it?

Comment: I'm not surprised by this response.  The video did not appear to be a video focused on accuracy.  It was clearly for entertainment.